# using GNU parallel with multiple commands

Tags: bash, unix

I am using GNU parallel to download a batch of file then I would like to compress them at the same time with gzip.

I have a list of https address of the file (http_list)

```
cat htpp_list | parallel -j 72 wget
```

it will download files with extension *.jpeg

then I do this:

```
ls -al *.jpeg | awk '{print $NF}' > file_list
cat file_list | parallel -j 72 gzip
```

Is there a way to write only in one line of code to download and compress at same time?

Comment: You have two input sources: `http_list` and `file_list`. It's not clear to me, how they are related. As a first step, write a single script which performs both actions (wget and gzip). Think about what argument it needs. Then use this script with `parallel`. After you got this working, try to think how to simplify it (or ask here at Stackoverflow).

Comment: `jpeg` files are already compressed and generally do not benefit much from gzip type compression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not parse ls. Use glob or `find`.

Do not abuse cats. Use `<file` instead of `cat file | command`.

Check your scripts with shellcheck.

> I would like to compress them at the same time with gzip.

I see no reason to store them uncompressed then.

```
work() {
   name=$(basename "$1")
   curl "$1" | gzip > "$name".jpeg.gz
}
export -f work
parallel -j 72 work <htpp_list
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```
cat htpp_list | parallel -j 72 wget; ls -al *.jpeg | awk '{print $NF}' | parallel -j 72 gzip
```

But think again because the line become quite complex